# How to create file watcher in shared webhosting environment

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-hosting

I have a windows shared web hosting, and i want to create there a file watcher which will monitor my images folder and resize the new images.
I thought to make it as a separate component because i may sell to others later.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody would pay for that, too easy to write. Just go ahead and integrate right in to the upload/whatever script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have a hard time implementing a file watcher in a shared environment. Usually the easiest way to implement something like that is to write it as a Windows service and use the built in .NET file/directory monitoring classes.

Unless you have the ability to install applications/services on your shared server, I think you're going to find that you're out of luck.